# Are we getting WinterBash hats?

Tags: discussion

Just seen [this](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3423/40657) question in the WP SE. So, wondering whether we would opt in this time or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see no reason not to - the site had hats last year. It's opt-out, meaning will be on by default. Post here if you object.

Comment: Nope.  That's a yay!  from my side.  Was planning to propose an opt-in.  :)